# Map Axios data outside of render in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call .map() on data from Axios before passing it into the return statement. The point of this is I want to use Material UI tables, and their pattern is to construct rows, then map the rows value in the return. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get (url,  {
      auth: {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }
    })
      .then(response => setData (response.data.result));

  }, [])


  function createData(id) {
    return {id}
  }

   const newArray = element => {
       data.map ({
        id: element.Id
       })
    return newArray
   }

    const rows = [
        createData(newArray.id)
    ]

    console.log(data)  //returns the correct array
    console.log(newArray.id)  //returns undefined
    console.log(rows) //returns id:undefined

  return (     
        <div>
          {rows.map(row => (
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.id}
              </TableCell>
          ))}
        </div>  
    )
}
```

Comment: The axios code is executed asynchronously, do you understand that?

Comment: can you update with your complete component?

Comment: newArray is a function here. Just use data.map and assign it directly into newArray.  That should solve the problem I guess

Comment: Could you upload to codesandbox or create a fiddle on jsfiddle and post the link so that we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `response.data.result` (from your axios request) is an array of objects with an `Id` property, for example:

```
[
  { Id: 1, ... },
  { Id: 2, ... }
]
```

...then perhaps something like this will solve your problem:

```
function Example(props) {
  const [ rows, setRows ] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(url, {
        auth: {
          username: username,
          password: password
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        // Assuming "response.data.result" is an array here
        const data = response.data.result
        const ids = data.map(element => {
          return { id: element.Id }
        })
        setRows(ids)
      });

  }, [])

  return (     
    <div>
      {rows.map(row => (
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {row.id}
        </TableCell>
      ))}
    </div>  
  )
}
```